# How to use Index formula to return a list based on multiple criterea

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am using the following array formula to attempt to return a list of job numbers ( in column A).

My conditions are based on the date in cell A3 , correlating to dates that match in column L
but also to only be true if the contents of the cell in column m = "Booked"

here is what i have and it seems to be working but only for the first condition, it is returning all jobs instead of just the ones with "booked" in column M

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('TRUSS JOBS AND DELIVERY'!A:A,SMALL(IFS('TRUSS JOBS AND DELIVERY'!L:L=A3,ROW('TRUSS JOBS AND DELIVERY'!A:A),ROW('TRUSS JOBS AND DELIVERY'!M:M),"BOOKED"),ROWS(B$3:B3))),"")
```

could anyone tell me what i am doing wrong here. i feel like maybe its the ifs formula, maybe there's a totally different way to do this.

Comment: Hi @Levi Panrucker, please provide a sample file to better understand the issue.

Comment: `ROW()` is designed to return a number. You are comparing that to text which should result in no matches. I'm guessing the attribute of row is also an issue (it is looking for a cell, not whatever `'TRUSS JOBS AND DELIVERY'!M:M` is. Finally, I don't think you can modify your `value_if_true` with formulas (cannot wrap that with row)

Comment: I think in this case ROWS() is working to define the array, as there are multiple cells that will return true i need them to list out, so i have an array of this formula working down about 20 rows or so in a table that is filtering the blanks. I will provide a sample today I will just have to create a desensitized version. If it helps at all my original formula looked like this before i tried to adapt it to a different sheet and use 2 if statements to return a result.

Comment: =IFERROR(INDEX('TRUSS JOBS AND DELIVERY'!A:A,SMALL(IF('TRUSS JOBS AND DELIVERY'!P:P=A3,ROW('TRUSS JOBS AND DELIVERY'!A:A)),ROWS(B$4:B4))),"")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or:

```
=FILTER('TRUSS JOBS AND DELIVERY'!A:M,('TRUSS JOBS AND DELIVERY'!L:L=A3)*('TRUSS JOBS AND DELIVERY'!M:M="Booked"))
```

Naturally, you'd want to replace the first range reference of `A:M` with `A:whatever the last column you want is`.

Absolutely, you'd also want to give some limit to those references so you are not evaluating millions of cells.

The easiest function for your need is `FILTER()`. You can give it an `IFERROR()` since it returns `#CALC!` for a no match lookup.

The piling up of criteria is simple using the old trick of placing the conditions inside parentheses `()` and multiplying the sets of parentheses by each other. You will usually see the trick include a `*1` at its start or end, but that is not needed. It is only needed when using the trick with a single condition (as that array must be multiplied by something to force it to 1's and 0's instead of TREU's and FALSE's, but in that case it often isn't needed at all because the function it is used in is happy with the TRUE/FALSE array itself.

Oddly, your solution, given in Comments, doesn't match the columns you said to use. Well, adjust the references as needed. This formula is set up to return ALL the columns in the range used. You have some options with that. You can wrap the formula (including the `IFERROR()` if you wish to have one) with `INDEX()` and:

1. Let it return all columns, though that'd be a little pointless.
2. Tell it which columns to return. Usually you do this with a simple array constant that looks something like `{1,3,4,5,8,21,23}` (whichever columns you want returned). If they have a neat pattern to them, you can even use `SEQUENCE()`. Note that you do NOT need to return columns L and M (used for the matching) unless you want them returned. They will still work nicely in the filtering.
3. You can not only choose which columns to return, but their order which need not match the original data's column order. You can even repeat columns if you wish. An array constant that does all those things might look like `{7,2,23,28,3,2,7,14,20}`.

`FILTER()` is very easy to use all by itself. Easy to add matching criteria for however many criteria you have. And inside an `INDEX()` it neatly gives you full control over columns returned.

Comment: Hi Jeorge, Thanks, that worked a treat, I did have to use index as there were multiple values. in another answer I will show the final formula which is adjusted slightly for each row of the formula. It was a bit of a pain to get it working as had to copy/ paste and redefine all the cell references manually and ctrl+shift+enter every cell. luckily I only had about 10 rows that I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1674495#1674734) I ended up with the formula below which had to be adjusted for every row to be able to
return multiple values.

For row 1 starting at C4:

```
{=INDEX(IFERROR(FILTER('sheet1!'!A:M,('sheet1!'!L:L=A3)*('sheet1!'!M:M="Booked")),),ROWS(C4:C4))}
```

For row 2 and so on:

```
{=INDEX(IFERROR(FILTER('sheet1!'!A:M,('sheet1!'!L:L=A3)*('sheet1!'!M:M="Booked")),),ROWS(C4:C5))}
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to get the `{}` and make the array formulas work.